# How use this select in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

i need use this select:

```
SELECT * FROM Anuncio_prestador WHERE ID = (SELECT Anuncio_prestador_info_ID 
FROM Anuncio WHERE Anuncio_perfil LIKE 'prestador' AND User_ID = 3)
```

but returns only one value and not all, 
how to proceed?

Comment: i changed (WHERE ID = ) to (WHERE ID IN) and worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that only one result won't match this?

```
User_ID = 3)
```